# Bootstrap Vue Modal showing duplicate in v-for

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal, vuex, bootstrap-vue

I have a list of sales that I get from the API, with a getter, which is injected on the component (through "items").
When you click on each sale, a modal shows up with the chronological info of the sale.
List of sales with modal at the end:

```js
     <b-list-group>
       <b-list-group-item
        :items="items"
        :per-page="perPage"
        :current-page="currentPage"
        id="my-orders"
        href="#"
        @click="orderTimeline(item.id)"
        v-b-modal="'sale-history'"
        v-for="item in items.slice(
          perPage * (currentPage - 1),
          perPage * currentPage
        )"
        :key="item.id"
      >
        <b-container class="text-center" fluid>
          <b-row>
            <b-col sm="2">{{ item.pyxis_id }}</b-col>
            <b-col sm="3">{{ item.title }}</b-col>
            <b-col sm="2">{{ item.subtitle }}</b-col>
            <b-col sm="2">{{ item.status }}</b-col>
            <b-col sm="2">{{ item.price }} €</b-col>
            <b-col sm="1"
              ><i style="float: right;" class="i-Arrow-Down"></i>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
        </b-container>
      </b-list-group-item>
    </b-list-group>

    <b-modal id="sale-history" size="lg" title="Cronologia de compra">
          <div v-for="sale in getSaleHistory" :key="sale.id">
            <b-container>
              <b-row class="justify-content-md-center">
                <b-col cols="3" md="auto">
                  <ul class="progress-bar">
                    <li></li>
                  </ul>
                </b-col>
                <b-col cols="9">
                  <b-row>
                    <b-col cols="6">
                      <h5>Data</h5>
                      <p>{{ sale.date }}</p>
                    </b-col>
                    <b-col cols="6">
                      <h5>Estado</h5>
                      <p>{{ sale.name }}</p>
                    </b-col>
                  </b-row>
                </b-col>
              </b-row>
            </b-container>
          </div>
        </b-modal>
```

then the JS

```js
    import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
    export default {
      props: {
        items: {
          type: Array,
          default: function() {
            return [];
          },
        },
        sale: {
          type: Array,
          default: function() {
            return [];
          },
        },
      },
      data() {
        return {
          perPage: 10,
          currentPage: 1,
        };
      },
```

So far so good.
The problem is that no matter what, it always shows up 2 modals with the exact same info, for each sale. It doesn't matter if I have 10 sales or 40 sales available to click on, it always shows 2 and I can't figure it out why.
Help?

Comment: I have run the code (as far, as it was possible) and it seems, that problem is not in the code snippets above. Probably, something is wrong with `orderTimeLine` function.

Comment: @Korgan the click method sets the sale Id in the store and dispatches the action that gets the saleHistory:
methods: {
    ...mapActions([
       "fetchSaleHistory"
       ]),
       orderTimeline (saleId) {
         this.$store.commit("setSaleId", saleId);
         this.$store.dispatch("fetchSaleHistory")
       }
  }

Comment: Is the `getSaleHistory()` functuon from the question the same thing as the `fetchSaleHistory()` from your comment?

Comment: @Korgan kind of, the `fetchSaleHistory()` is the action dispatched to get the info from `getSaleHistory()` - they are connected.

Comment: I don't fully understand, how your vuex storage works, and thus, can't simulate it with the same issue. Could you please add a the required part of `Vuex.Store`.

Comment: @Korgan sure!
`const state = {
  orders: {
    saleId: 0,
    saleHistory: "",
  },
};
const getters = {
getSaleHistory(state, getters) {
    return state.orders.saleHistory;},},
const mutations = {
setSaleHistory(state, saleHistory) {
    state.orders.saleHistory = saleHistory; },},
const actions = {
fetchSaleHistory: async function({ commit, getters, rootState }) {
    try {
      const response = await Vue.axios.get(
        "http://localhost:80/stores/");
      let saleHistory = response.data;
      commit("setSaleHistory", saleHistory); }}}`

Comment: How do you get `saleId`, to load `saleHistory` from your API? The reason of duplication could be the usage of `getters` property instead of `rootState`? And what is the readon tho have `sale` prop in this component (looks confuzing)?

Comment: @Korgan I have to pass the sale ID to get the info just related to that sale (when the modal opens) and I use the following method:
`orderTimeline (saleId) {
         this.$store.commit("setSaleId", saleId);
         this.$store.dispatch("fetchSaleHistory")}`
How do I use `rootState` instead of `getters`?

Comment: I mean, to use `rootState` in the `fetchSaleHistory` action. When you call `setSaleId`, you change the id parameter, which, as far, as I understand, should be used to load info about sales for selected item. To get the current version of id you should call `rootState.stateId`.

Comment: @Korgan I tried to use `rootSate.saleId` (and not as you mentioned `rootSate.stateId`) but it didn't work. Exactly, when I click on the sale, I want the store to update the sale Id I want to look for, and then the fetchSaleHistory is dispatched in order to get the info of that sale from the API. However, it still shows me 2 modal... Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need `sale` prop in your vue-component?

Comment: Look at [this git repo](https://github.com/MefAldemisov/VuexTest): I've cloned everything, that was previously discussed, but still don't have 2 modals.

Comment: @Korgan I tried like you did, but it doesn't work. Where you have `item.pyxis_id`, it has to be `item.id`. Can it be because of that? Because I'm setting 2 keys with the same `item.id`?
(On another note, the `getSaleHistory` in the `v-for="sale in getSaleHistory"` is a getter and not a function)

Comment: I am not sure, that it can be the reason, however, have you thought about slight architecture changes: separate `modal` component and pass the required id to the props? In this case you will for sure remove the issue with duplicated data.

Comment: @Korgan I just tried that, using a component inside the modal and it still showed a duplicate modal. wtf.
`<b-modal id="sale-history" title="Cronologia de compra" ok-only>
<sale-history :items="getSaleHistory"></sale-history>
</b-modal>`

Comment: Try to call `getSaleHistory` as a function. In my case it doesn't even work without braces.

Comment: @Korgan if I do that, it doesn't work. It tells me that `getSaleHistory` in not a function :\

Comment: Could you, please, isolate the code (~how it was done in got repo) and share the it. I don't know, how to reproduce your bug.

Comment: @Korgan I've found the problem! This list was inserted in some tabs. Each tab had the same modal call, so when I called in one tab, the modal was being called in every tab as well (2 tabs in total, hence the duplicate modal). I took the modal out of the tab and it ran great!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem) Congratulations!